# OR Tools - Creating Distance Matrix

Tags: python, or-tools

I am using Google OR Tools for solving the capacitated vehicle routing problem with pickups and deliveries. I am importing distance matrix from MSSQL database and struggling to formulate the distance matrix.

Following are the tasks to be delivered :

```
taskid              SiteID
CFR                 CFRC21126412A8612122
CFRORFC2207-002969  CFRC21126412A8612122
CFRORFC2207-003940  CFRC21085782A8615004
DC VISIT            CFRP30036
```

We also have times and distance in database, hence formulated the matrix as such:

[image: SQL Matrix]

Just struggling to see how I can output this to distance and time matrix as per required by [VRP](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/pickup_delivery) . Following is my drafted code :

```
    with sqlConn.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[get_Active_Tasks_Origin_Destination]')
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    dd=[]

    for i in range(len(tasks)):
        row=[]
        for j in range(len(tasks)): ##what to loop here
            print("dat i j={}".format(result[i][3]))  ##need to get Average KM or Time here
            row.append(result[i][4])
        dd.append(row)
    print(type(dd[0][1]))
```

Following is my result[i]

```
result[i]
('CFR', 'CFRORFC2207-003940', 'CFRC21126412A8612122', 'CFRC21085782A8615004', 0.297, 0.0399742)
```

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? When you say "distance and time matrix", what format do these have? First you need to describe in words what your desired result should be.

Comment: OR-Tools ConstraintSolver works with integers, your distances will have to be scaled up to be able to use integers.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - that's my first problem - not understanding how distance matrix works in VRP

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins  - I can scale up distance from KM to M, but do you know how should I formulate distance matrix based on my example above?

Comment: In the page of the VRP example (your VRP link) there is a link to the "previous example" at https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp#entire_program1 which shows a distance matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is my eventual solution:

1. Store the results in Panda's DataFrame

   ```
    with sqlConn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(f'EXEC [dbo].[get_Active_Tasks_Origin_Destination_v2] ?', str(tenantid_num))
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(), columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description])
    cursor.close()
   ```
2. Use the pivot_table method to create the matrix

   ```
    data['time_matrix'] = df.pivot_table(index='Origin_TaskID', columns='Destn_TaskID', values='AvgKM').fillna(0)
    data['dist_matrix'] = df.pivot_table(index='Origin_TaskID', columns='Destn_TaskID', values='AvgTime').fillna(0)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

> Just struggling to see how I can output this to distance and time matrix as per required by VRP .

When using OR-tools to solve VRP, you don't necessarily need a distance or time matrix. You can provide a callback to calculate the distance between two nodes. This allows you the freedom to represent the distance in any way you want.

Here are some options:

1. A 2D list. Let's call it `mat`. Then you get the distance from node `i` to node `j` by doing `mat[i][j]`. The limitation is that `i` and `j` must be integers.
2. Nested dictionaries. This uses the exact same syntax as a 2D list, but now `i` and `j` can be whatever type you want (as long as it is hashable). So for example, you can use strings as the indexes.
3. Use the dataframe directly. Both of the other options require that you transform your dataframe into another data structure. You can use the dataframe directly and implement logic to get the distance from it.

Source: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrp